# ForEach Loop on Properties of different objects but of same type

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, iphone, uikit

This is the problem function:

```
func setStateForAudioIOControls(enabled: Bool) {
   let finalColor = enabled ? audioIOView.enabledColor : audioIOView.disabledColor
   [audioIOView.enableButton.configuration?.background.backgroundColor, audioIOView.disableButton.configuration?.background.backgroundColor].forEach { backgroundColor in
      backgroundColor = finalColor
   }
}
```

When I try to implement a `ForEach` loop on the `UIColor` properties in this array I get the error: `Cannot convert value of type '(inout UIColor?) -> ()' to expected argument type '(UIColor?) throws -> Void`

However, when I change the function to:

```
func setStateForAudioIOControls(enabled: Bool) {
    let finalColor = enabled ? audioIOView.enabledColor : audioIOView.disabledColor
    audioIOView.slider.tintColor = finalColor
    [audioIOView.enableButton, audioIOView.disableButton].forEach { button in
        button.configuration?.background.backgroundColor = finalColor
    }
}
```

The error goes away and the color value changes successfully. I want to implement the function as the top one (where I'm loop directly over an array of colors) so that I can use this `ForEach` on different classes (e.g. changing the slider tint color). Any idea why the first one doesn't work but the second one does? They ultimately are trying to do the same thing.

Comment: The first is iterating through an array of `UIColor` references. But you can't take that pointer to a `UIColor` object and replace it with a completely different color object (which is why it fails). Whereas your second example, you are passing an array of buttons, and updating a mutable property of that button, which is why it works.

Comment: @Rob So then instead of changing the pointer to an object, I would have to set the values of the thing being pointed at to match those of `finalColor`?

Comment: Bottom line, you can iterate through the array and perform some action on each item (i.e., your second example), but you can't replace just items in the array through which you are currently iterating (your first example).